# npm debug can i invoke with multiple names

Tags: node.js, node-debugger

Currently I am initializing the debug module by

```
import express = require('express');
import debug = require('debug');

var routeLogger = debug('myapp:routes:index');
var router = express.Router();
routeLogger('Start setting up index route');
```

I am wondering if i can put more than one name to the debug function? such as `debug('myapp,routes,indexRoute')`